# Selenium2Library: move mouse position for click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to the whole Robotframework and the Selenium2Library and I have a problem.

I have two divs: *rasterContainer* and *anlageContainer*.
They have the same x- and y-offset. The *anlageContainer* has a z-offset of 3 and the *rasterContainer* has 0. The *anlageContainer* lies on top of the *rasterContainer*.
Those two build a time bar.The *anlageContainer* got just one id and the *rasterContainer* contains many other divs, each of them with an id.
If you mouse over those divs, the *rasterContainer* shows you the time. If you click there, you just click on the *anlageContainer* and some other methods calculate the offset to get the time and opens a window with this time in a textbox.

What I want to do:

I want to move my mouse to an element of the *rasterContainer* and click at the same position on the *anlageContainer*.

What I have tried:

I began to write my own library in python. I have just one method which gets an instance of the Selenium2Library, the vertical value of the mouse position (the mouse is on top of the *anlageContainer*) and the vertical value of the *rasterContainer*'s element.

```
def click_on_element(self, vertEl, vertMo, se2lib):       
    v = vertEl - vertMo 

    #Get Webdriver
    driver = se2lib._current_browser()

    #ActionChains instance
    ac = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

    ac.move_by_offset(0, v)                 
    ac.click().perform()        

    return "On my way"
```

With **move_by_offset**:  The window opens but with the wrong time (07:00). I wanted to have 09:30.

I also tried:

```
    #Get Element
    elmfinder = ElementFinder()
    elm = elmfinder.find(driver, "5_09_30")[0]
    ac.move_to_element(elm)
    ac.move_to_element_with_offset(elm, 461, 422)
```

The window opened neither with **move_to_element** nor with **move_to_element_with_offset**.

I really don't know what I am missing here.

Any hints would help.

EDIT:
HTML code:

```
<div id="resource_id_5_2013-07-30" class="resource" daylenght="720" loaded="false"   date="2013-07-30" time="07:00" style="top: 0px; height: 1540px; width: 309.75px; left: 619.5px;">
  <div class="terminContainer"></div>
  <div class="overlapContainer" style="width: 10%; position: absolute; left: 90%; height: 1560.0px; top: 0px;"></div>
  <div id="5" class="anlageContainer" style="width: 10%; height: 1440px; top: 0px;" title="08:53"></div>
  <div class="rasterContainer" style="width: 10%; height: 1440px; top: 0px;">
    <div id="5_07_00" class="rasterLabel" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;">7:00</div>
    <div id="5_07_15" class="rasterLabel" style="position: absolute; top: 30px;">7:15</div>
    <div id="5_07_30" class="rasterLabel" style="position: absolute; top: 60px;">7:30</div>
    etc...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS style:

```
.rasterContainer{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.anlageContainer:hover + .rasterContainer{
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.rasterLabel{
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #000;
  border-top: solid 1px #888;
}

.anlageContainer{
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```

There you can see that the *anlageContainer* is above the *rasterContainer*. And between them are the *rasterLabels* --> z-index.

The *anlageContainer* has

```
dojo.connect(anlageContainer, 'onclick', function(clickevt){
    addTermin(resourceId, getOffsetY(clickevt)/g_terminMultiplikator, datum);
});
```

Two links to images:

[Time bar](http://software.digithurst.de/stackoverflow/zeitleiste.png)

[3D time bar](http://software.digithurst.de/stackoverflow/3d%20zeitleiste.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
element = find_element_by_xpath (driver, ".//div[@id='resource_id_5_2013-07-30']//div[@class='anlageContainer']")
element.click()
```

Comment: the problem I have is that I want to move the mouse but it doesn't. It always gets the 07:00 instead of the 09:30.

Comment: once you have found the element, try printing it's content. If it has wrong content, you have found the wrong element. There must be some problem with your xpah

Comment: I get the element, but I don't want to click the element. I want to click the _anlageContainer_ which lies above this element. Therefore I try to put the mouse onto the _anlageContainer_ and move the mouse downwards where the vertical offset is the same as the one of the element (5_09_30) and click. But the mouse won't get moved...

Comment: Using ac.move_to_element_with_offset function you cannot move away from the element. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407790/selenium-python-driver-function-move-to-element-with-offset-incorrect-behavior. All you can do is move within the element. That too not beyond the center of the element.

Comment: Oh, that's bad.. Is there any way or workaround to make the mouse move?

Comment: You have to find an alternate method. There should be some way to click on the element you wanted. Why can't you findElement based on that? Can you share your html and specify which element you want to click?

Comment: With your code I can click on the _anlageContainer_, that's cool, but I just click on the same position every time. The _anlageContainer_ is not just a small div, it's the time bar shown in the picture "Time bar". I want to click, for example, at the position where the 09_30 is shown. You know what I mean? The _anlageContainer_ takes the y-offset and calculates the time, eg: offset: 301/2 = 150,5 => 09:30..

Comment: can you find any URL patterns by clicking on different y-offset?
If not, you can try your move_to_element function after selecting 'anlageContainer'

Comment: There are no URL patterns and I tried your idea but it always opens at 7:00.. :/

Comment: Capture the request that is sent from your browser when you open at 9.30. You can find the request using firebug -> console. If you can find the request, you can just request it explicitly.

Comment: There is no request, everything's done in the javascript.. I'll try to execute the javascript but it's a bit tricky. Its' not just one function... Thanks for your help!