# click at at an arbitrary position in web browser with selenium 2 (Python binding)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting confused trying to find a way to **send the left-click in a web browser window in a specific point**. I am using Selenium `selenium-2.44.0` and Python 2.7. My ultimate goal is to be able to click in certain areas in the window, but for now I just want to make sure I am able to click at all. I thought that clicking on an area where a link is located is a good idea because then I will be able to verify the click did occur (i.e., I will be taken to another html page).

All the prerequisites are met, I am able to start the browser and access and manipulate various web elements. From what I've found in the Help, one is supposed to use [move_by_offset](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset) method to move the mouse cursor into a certain direction. However, **when I run the code, the click doesn't occur (or it occurs, but the url link is not clicked and no new page opens)**. I cannot even verify whether the click occurred. When clicking the Logout link, for instance, in a normal browser session, the logout operation occurs.

```
...
homeLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
homeLink.click() #clicking on the Home button and mouse cursor should? stay here
print homeLink.size, homeLink.location

helpLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Help")
print helpLink.size, helpLink.location

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(150,0) #move 150 pixels to the right to access Help link
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Here is the screenshot of the area in the web page I am working with.

[image]

The size and location of the elements are printed as below:

```
{'width': 39, 'height': 16} {'y': 47, 'x': 341}
{'width': 30, 'height': 16} {'y': 47, 'x': 457}
```

The html code behind the page is below, if it's worth looking at.

```
<a href="/web/">Home</a>
|
<a href="/web/Account/LogOff">Logout</a>
|
<a href="#" onclick="HelpFile.open();">Help</a>
```

I know that I can access the link by finding an element in many ways, but I am trying to perform a click in a certain location and am using the link element just to verify the click really occurred.

**How do perform the click?**

Comment: How did you calculate 150 pixel offset to access the help link?

Comment: @shri046, I found the difference between the x coordinates of the Home link and the Help link (in the question body the print element.size). I've also verified that by using the MeasureIt add-on to Firefox.

Comment: In my experience, click always happens in the middle (center) of an element. So `homeLink.click()` will probably have the mouse pointer at x + (width/2) of the home link element. You may have to take that into account when calculating your resulting offset that you need to move to.

Comment: That is a very valid point, thank you. I will test more with various offset values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is nothing else going on on your page that would interfere with the click, this should do it:

```
homeLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
homeLink.click() #clicking on the Home button and mouse cursor should? stay here
print homeLink.size, homeLink.location

helpLink = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Help")
print helpLink.size, helpLink.location

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(homeLink, 150, 0) #move 150 pixels to the right to access Help link
action.click()
action.perform()
```

You should use [`move_to_element_with_offset`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset) if you want the mouse position to be relative to an element. Otherwise, [`move_by_offset`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset) moves the mouse relative to the previous mouse position. When you using `click` or `move_to_element`, the mouse is placed in the center of the element. (The [Java documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#click%28org.openqa.selenium.WebElement%29) about these is explicit.)

Comment: Hey @Louis, thanks for the help. I've edited my question specifying that I submit the click on the Home button first. Does it bring the mouse cursor over the Home button? If so, then I would expect the move_by_offset to move the cursor to the right from the Home button. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Did you try the code I wrote and did it fix the problem? Note that it is generally not a good idea to change your question like you did after you get answers like mine, because it makes people who answered the earlier version of your question look as if they did not pay attention to what you wrote.

Comment: your answer is still valid after my edit, but I will keep in mind your note. The code you've published does work, but it will clicking the Help button whatever offset I specified (500,500 e.g.). Another thing that I think I've specified in the question is that I don't know to what element I will have to move my mouse cursor to. I just want to be able to move 150 pixels right from a know location and then left-click without knowing what is underneath it. The Help/Home links are just for visualization and workflow verification purposes.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how this code works. The offset is from top-left corner of the specified element so ideally the click should happen outside the help link? Reason I ask is because of [similar issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407790/selenium-python-driver-function-move-to-element-with-offset-incorrect-behavior) others have reported with regards to this function.

Comment: @shri046 I put a reference to the wrong element in there. Fixed now.

Comment: @Louis Ah yes, that makes more sense. What threw me off was Alex's comment that the previous code was working. That basically means it is either a defect where offset is not being respected or he interpreted the right element reference.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say for you exact situation but I know a workaround to the question in the summary and bold

> send the left-click in a web browser window in a specific point

You just use execute_script and do the clicking using javascript.

```
self.driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(47, 457); el.click();')
```

It's convenient in a pinch because you can debug find the coordinates of an element in a browser by opening console and using querySelector (works the same as Webdriver's By.CSS_SELECTOR):

```
el = document.querySelector('div > h1');
var boundaries = el.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(boundaries.top, boundaries.right, boundaries.bottom, boundaries.left);
```

That being said, it's a really bad idea to write your tests to click a specific point. But I have found that sometimes even when el.click() or an [action chain](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) aren't working, execute script will still work using a querySelector which is about as good as what you would be doing in Selenium.

```
self.driver.execute_script('el = document.querySelector("div > h1"); el.click();')
```